# why is my view all black after initiating a simple "performSegueWithIdentifier"?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uiview, segue

I'm just attempting to initiate a simple segue programmatically, but for some reason, when I do so, the destination view is just all black, and when I go back via the navigation controller, it turns the rest of my views black as well. Here is the segue in my IB:

[image]

And this the code for the segue, through a button in the master controller:

```
@IBAction func buttonPressed(sender: AnyObject) {

        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("showLoading", sender: self)
    }
```

however when I run the app and press the button, the segue works but the view is just black:

[image]

and every view previous is black as well.. but i have notices every time i switch back and forth between the tabs, the views are regular and not this black screen. Why is this unusual behavior occurring?

Comment: did you assign a class to that controller

Comment: I see in your screenshots that one view has a dark background. Is it maybe an inheritance issue? With navigation controllers subsequent views  inherit the color of the navigation controller. That is the only way I can replicate something like what you are describing

Comment: no thats just the uiimageview's image in that view. its the background. @RMenke

Comment: the view that I'm sending the segue from isn't manually connected in the IB, it was instantiated in a previous view, so would that make any difference? @RMenke

Comment: the view that I'm sending the segue from isn't manually connected in the IB, it was instantiated in a previous view, so would that make any difference? @Lamar

Comment: The view's not instantiated properly, and if you're using `performWithSegue` you must use storyboard otherwise use the equivalent to `presentViewController`

Comment: its not instantiated correctly how? and your saying i can't perform a segue from the story board programmatically?

Comment: have you tried with the `Debug View Hierachy` tool? It will tell you which view is actually black and then we can be more helpful with the why part ;)

Comment: how do I use that tool?

Answer (score 0):

Once I disable the sizeclass of my storyboard.

Change one of popover segue to push segue.

Then I enable the sizeclass,this segue is the same as yours in storyboard ,so is the problem .

[image]

After I change this segue back to popover segue, everything works fine again.
[image]

This is how I fix this problem ,but I don't know why.

And the following is my code in presentedviewcontroller:

```
    // MARK: - Navigation

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
 if segue.identifier == Constants.EditWaypointSegue {
        if let waypoint = (sender as? MKAnnotationView)?.annotation as? EditableWaypoint {
            if let ewvc = segue.destinationViewController.contentViewController as? EditWaypointViewController {
                if let ppc = ewvc.popoverPresentationController {
                    let coordinatePoint = mapView.convertCoordinate(waypoint.coordinate, toPointToView: mapView)
                    ppc.sourceRect = (sender as! MKAnnotationView).popoverSourceRectForCoordinatePoint(coordinatePoint)
                    let minimumSize = ewvc.view.systemLayoutSizeFittingSize(UILayoutFittingCompressedSize)
                    ewvc.preferredContentSize = CGSize(width: Constants.EditWaypointPopoverWidth, height: minimumSize.height)
                    ppc.delegate = self
                }
                ewvc.waypointToEdit = waypoint
            }
        }
    }
}

// MARK: - UIAdaptivePresentationControllerDelegate

func adaptivePresentationStyleForPresentationController(controller: UIPresentationController) -> UIModalPresentationStyle {
    println("full")
    return UIModalPresentationStyle.FullScreen // full screen, but we can see what's underneath
}
func presentationController(controller: UIPresentationController, viewControllerForAdaptivePresentationStyle style: UIModalPresentationStyle) -> UIViewController?
{
    let navcon = UINavigationController(rootViewController: controller.presentedViewController)
    let visualEffectView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: UIBlurEffect(style: .ExtraLight))
    visualEffectView.frame = navcon.view.bounds
    navcon.view.insertSubview(visualEffectView, atIndex: 0) // "back-most" subview
    return navcon
}
```

Comment: i don't have a popover segue in my storyboard

Comment: @MikeStrong  I post the code, in case someone found something in it.You should try to delete the segue,and recreate it ,to see what would happen.